# Using PortCMIS to add Secondary fields for multiple types

Tags: vb.net, cmis

I have a list of objects that are part of a given document type and a few Secondary fields that belong to multiple types. 
When I look at the examples I should be able to add the fields to the property dictionary. but I currently do not understand how to add multiple types. 
I found an example referring to select statements, but that does not translate particularly well for me...

A IBackendField object contains the name and aspect and value of a field.

AbsoluteId is something like "P:cm:indexControl_cmis:name" 
Id would then be "cmis:name"

The property list that is returned by this function is then provided as the first argument of the CreateDocument function of PortCMIS.

The Alfresco server I talk to also expects to also see P:cm:generalclassifiable but I'm unsure how to add that.

```
Private Function ProcessValues(ByVal fields As List(Of IBackendField)) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim secondaryTypesadded As Boolean = False
        Dim properties = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim secondaryTypes = New List(Of String)

        For Each f As IBackendField In fields
            If f.IsPrimary Then
                properties.Add(f.Id, ProcessValue(f))
            Else
                secondaryTypes.Add(Left(f.AbsoluteId, InStr(f.AbsoluteId, "_") - 1))  
                secondaryTypesadded = True
            End If
        Next

        If secondaryTypesadded Then
            properties(PropertyIds.SecondaryObjectTypeIds) = secondaryTypes
        End If

        For Each f As IBackendField In fields
            If Not f.IsPrimary Then
                properties.Add(f.Id, ProcessValue(f))
            End If
        Next

        Return properties
    End Function
```